# Camunda Spring Boot Starter version 1.1 to 1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

Lately I've updated from camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter version 1.1 to version 1.3.
One of the changes for the framework is the "DefaultProcessEngineConfiguration" class.

version 1.1.0

```
public class DefaultProcessEngineConfiguration extends AbstractCamundaConfiguration implements CamundaProcessEngineConfiguration {
  ...
  public void apply(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration configuration) {...}
}
```

version 1.3.0

```
public class DefaultProcessEngineConfiguration extends AbstractCamundaConfiguration implements CamundaProcessEngineConfiguration {
  ...
  public void preInit(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration configuration) {...}
}
```

Is it just a name change? Or is it both methods means different things?
I've been trying to find out more online, but very limited information.

Comment: Been looking at the framework code. The "CamundaBpmConfiguration" class has different implementation of processEngineConfigurationImpl(), where as the earlier version calls the apply(), wonder if this might be the key.

Answer (score 0):

Before 1.3 we used a custom interface to modify engine configurations. With 1.3 we switched to camundas default interface "ProcessEnginePlugin". This provides preInit(), postInit() and postEngineBuild() hooks and is both, more poweerful and standard compliant.
If you are using custom configuration extensions, just rename the method and you are good to go.